# convert string to a number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to parse a user input which contains longitude and latitude. What I want to do is to coerce a string to a number, preserving its sign and decimal places. But what I want to do is to display a message when user's input is invalid. Which one should I follow

```
parseFloat(x)
```

second

```
new Number(x)
```

third

```
~~x
```

fourth

```
+x
```

Comment: Never use `new Number()`, if any, use `Number()`. It depends on what kind of input you consider is valid. E.g. `parseFloat` will accept `"123foo"` and return `123` but `Number` (or the unary `+`) will return `NaN`.

Comment: Yes good point: you can use the `Number()` constructor as a plain function though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a string to an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/convert-a-string-to-an-integer)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd use `Number(x)`, if I had to choose between those two, because it won't allow trailing garbage. (Well, it "allows" it, but the result is a `NaN`.)

That is, `Number("123.45balloon")` is `NaN`, but `parseFloat("123.45balloon")` is `123.45` (as a number).

As Mr. Kling points out, which of those is "better" is up to you.

*edit* — ah, you've added back `+x` and `~~x`.  As I wrote in a comment, `+x` is equivalent to using the `Number()` constructor, but I think it's a little risky because of the syntactic flexibility of the `+` operator. That is, it'd be easy for a cut-and-paste to introduce an error.  The `~~x` form is good if you know you want an integer (a 32-bit integer) anyway. For lat/long that's probably not what you want however.

Comment: what do you think about `+x`?

Comment: @m.abbas well it's probably equivalent to `Number()` but personally I would stay away from it as it's "syntactically fragile" (I just made that term up). That's just me being paranoid however.

Comment: Really? I love `+` :) The behaviour is well defined but it might not be obvious to everyone what it means/does (similar to `~~`).

Comment: @FelixKling yes but as I note in my amendment it scares me because `+` is so crazy.  Just a personal quirk I guess.

Comment: ok @Pointy thank you for your reply! But as @Felix Kling said, it is not obvious to everyone and personally, i prefer to use `+` instead of the other functions.

Comment: @Pointy The benefit of using `+` is the speed, as is shown in my answer's link.

Comment: @Engineer interesting, but a [simple jsperf](http://jsperf.com/numbers-from-strings) suggests that in newer browsers it's probably not much of a difference.

Comment: @Pointy I am not familiar with `jsperf`. Can you remove `Math.random()` part, and just hardcode values? That `random` could be the reason of incorrect results.

Comment: @Engineer well the randomness just sets up a set of strings to convert, and both tests use the same strings. Feel free to play around with it; you can modify other people's tests if you like.

Comment: @Pointy The tests show, that depends on browser, `+` can be faster or slower than `Number`. Probably in old browsers `+` is much more faster, but now it's not so.

Comment: Yes I agree - for validating user input the performance is probably not a huge deal anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The first one is better. It is explicit, and it is correct. You said you want to parse floating point numbers. `~~x` will give you an integer.

Comment: could you tell me why the first one is better?

Comment: @al0neevenings parseFloat(x), +x, new Number(x) all perform roughly the same function, they parse the string in similar ways. parseFloat(x) returns a float every time, and is explicitly telling you that it is parsing a float. makes for readability.

Comment: Explicit, readable code is usually better (unless it's overly verbose). Terse hacks like `~~x` limit the readability of your code and should be avoided unless you're really tight on space for some reason (like a short JavaScript coding compo). And in your case `~~x` is not even a valid solution because it gives you an integer.

Comment: @elclanrs Using +x can be confusing since + is also the string concat and addition operator.

Comment: How about if checking for the sign? I mean longitude or latitude could be negative. So is parseFloat(x) the best way to validate?

Comment: **@Hans Z** mmm...and `~~` is not confusing? I guess "confusing" depends on the developer...

Comment: The only problem I have with `parseFloat()` is that it ignores non-numeric characters after the number. Thus a string that starts with digits but then ends with random other characters can still be parsed, and it won't be a `NaN`. For some applications that may be OK of course.

Comment: @al0neevenings Why don't you try and see with a few simple samples? Just write this in your JS console, or go to jsfiddle.net to experiment: `parseFloat("-42.42")`

Comment: @Pointy then I think Number(x) would be the best way to go with. Is it correct?

Comment: Like I said, it would be my personal preference, but `+x` is shorter and there's nothing wrong with using it. (Using it in parentheses `(+x)` would solve the syntax issue anyway, and that's still shorter than `Number(x)` :-)

Answer (score 3):

To test whether `input` is number, use this:

```
function isNumeric(obj){
    return !isNaN( parseFloat(obj) ) && isFinite( obj );
}
```

To cast `String` to `Number`, use `+` ,[it's the fastest method](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/#tcNumber):

> the unary + operator also type-converts its operand to a number and because it does not do any additional mathematical operations it is the fastest method for type-converting a string into a number

So overall, probably you need this:

```
if(!isNumeric(inputValue)){
    alert('invalid number');
}else{
    var num = +inputValue;
}
```

<sub>`isNumeric` borrowed from `jQuery`</sub>

Comment: If you the `isNumeric` test, the efficiency of `+x` will become moot :) Maybe a `isNaN(num)` check after the conversion is better.

Comment: @AtesGoral What you suggest, is not proved (I mean `isNaN`), what I have posted is already proved.So I will choose the reliable way.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I would write to repeatedly take input until the correct one is obtained.

```
var d;

do {
    d = prompt("Enter a number");
    d = new Number(d);
} while( isNaN(d) );

document.write( d );
```

**Note:** `new Number(d)` will always give `NaN` if any character is non-numeric while `parseFloat(d)` will ignore trailing invalid characters.