# Calculate parseint with decimal

Tags: javascript, parsing, decimal, parseint

I found this in another post:

```
<script language='javascript'>
function AddInputs()
{
var total = 0;
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName('add')
for ( var i = 0; i<coll.length; i++)
{
    var ele = coll[i];
    total += parseInt(ele.value);
}
var Display = document.getElementById('Display');
Display.innerHTML = total;
}
</script>
```

It works, but 1.50, 1.50, and 1.50 = 3 which isn't accurate. I'm new to JS (only know PHP), but I looked into it and figure it has something to do with parseInt since 1.50 isn't a whole number. Is there something I can replace parseInt with to calculate it so that the three 1.50 actually equals 4.50?

Comment: You might also find [*convert string to a number in javascript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613705/convert-string-to-a-number-in-javascript) helpful. And when you discover that `0.1 + 0.2 !== 0.3` you'll want to read the answers to [*Elegant workaround for JavaScript floating point number problem*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem). ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`

Also use `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script language="javascript">` that will be more standard and correct

Comment: The *type* attribute for script elements is optional and defaults to *text/javascript*, so mostly it's not used at all. The language attribute was deprecated in HTML 4 and removed in HTML5.

Comment: Yes you're right. thanks.
script language attribute is wrong anyway.

Answer (score 1):

parseInt will convert any decimal to an integer so `parseInt(1.5)` becomes `1`. That is why parseInt(1.5) + parseInt(1.5) + parseInt(1.5) = 3. If you want it to equal 4.5 then just replace parseInt with parseFloat:

```
function AddInputs()
{
  var total = 0;
  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName('add')
  for ( var i = 0; i<coll.length; i++)
  {
    var ele = coll[i];
    total += parseFloat(ele.value);
  }
  var Display = document.getElementById('Display');
  Display.innerHTML = total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `parseInt` on 1.50 you're getting the integer part of that value (1 in this case). Just replace `parseInt` with `parseFloat` and you'll get the value you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Beside `parseFloat` you can also use `Number` to convert a string to a numeric value.

```js
document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', addNumber) 
var total = 0;

function addNumber(e) {
  total += Number(document.querySelector('#plus').value);
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = 'total: '+total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<input id="plus" type="number" placeholder="type a number"/>

<button id="add">add to total</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```